# Binding not working with TryUpdateModel but same thing working with Bind

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a asp.net mvc controller and I am facing a strange problem. When I tried to bind the model using Bind with whitelisting items it is working fine but when I tried to bind using the TryUpdateModel with include properties the same thing is not working. My code is pretty much standard.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index([Bind(include="firstname,lastname")]PersonModel model){
  .......
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Index(){
   var model = new PersonModel();
   var isBinding = TryUpdateModel(model,includeProperties:new[]{"firstName","lastname"})
  .......
}
```

Even though it is not binding, isBinding is set to true. Can any please suggest me why TryUpdateModel is not working but Bind is working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `TryUpdateModel()` not updating your model binding state in the second `Index` action is that you may binding instance of `PersonModel` with property values of `firstname` and `lastname` still set to empty (or even null value).

You can use this setup to bind the model with `TryUpdateModel`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index([Bind(Include = "firstname, lastname")] PersonModel model)
{
    if (TryUpdateModel(model))
    {
        // save changes with await
    }

    return View();
}
```

Or using `FormCollection` as alternative:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FormCollection form)
{
    var model = new PersonModel();
    if (TryUpdateModel(model, string.Empty, new [] { "firstname", "lastname" }, null, form))
    {
        // save changes with await
    }

    return View();
}
```

However, I think it's better to setup a viewmodel which includes all required properties and bound from there, since `TryUpdateModel()` method [has security note you should pay attention to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
// Model
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

// Controller action
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(PersonViewModel model)
{
    var data = new PersonModel();
    data.FirstName = model.FirstName;
    data.LastName = model.LastName;

    // save changes with await

    return View();
}
```

Related issues:

[How do I edit a FormCollection value, and then use TryUpdateModel with the edited collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550194/how-do-i-edit-a-formcollection-value-and-then-use-tryupdatemodel-with-the-edite)

[When and why do you use TryUpdateModel in asp.net mvc 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268421/when-and-why-do-you-use-tryupdatemodel-in-asp-net-mvc-2)

[Using TryUpdateModel to save an object on Edit Post with FormCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657898/using-tryupdatemodel-to-save-an-object-on-edit-post-with-formcollection)

Comment: Not sure why you are suggesting to use both Bind and TryUpdateModel on same program(Example 1). https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx article suggest to use either Bind or TryUpdateModel